# KIVY ERROR: Exception: ScrollView accept only one widget

Tags: python, graphics, kivy

I was trying to run this program but I get this error and i dont know what it means. If someone could show how to fix it I would be very grateful.
##################################################
python 3.8
on pycharm

PYTHON FILE:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
import os

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Davide\\PycharmProjects\\RUBRICA")
data_cont = []
first_imp = False

class Introduction1Window(Screen):
    def go_to_int2(self):
        application.sm.current = application.screens[2].name

class Introduction2Window(Screen):
    file_chooser: ObjectProperty(None)
    dir = "C:\\Program Files"

    def go_to_main(self):
        application.sm.switch_to(application.screens[0])
    def set_dir(self):
        self.dir = self.file_chooser.path

class NewContact(Screen):
    pass

class ModContact(Screen):
    pass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class Main(App):

    sm = None
    screens = [MainWindow(name="MainWindow"),Introduction1Window(name="Introduction1Window"),Introduction2Window(name="Introduction2Window(Screen)")]
    kv = None

    def build(self):
        self.sm = WindowManager()
        for screen in self.screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)
        if first_imp:
            self.sm.current = "Introduction1Window"
        else:
            self.sm.current = "MainWindow"
        self.screens[0].ids.lista_di_dati.data = [{'text='+ str(x)} for x in range(30)]
        return self.sm


application = Main()
application.run()
```

###############################################################à
KIVY FILE:

```
#: include newcontact.kv
#: include modcontact.kv
#: include introductionwindows.kv
#: include labels.kv
##: include datalayout.kv

<RecViewCustom@RecycleView>:
    viewclass: "Button"
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        id: 'lista_di_dati'
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: 1
        orientation: 'vertical'

MainWindow:
    #on_enter: root.load_rec_view()
    name: "MainWindow"
    orientation: "vertical"
    viewclass: "Label"
    Label:
        text: "main"
    RecViewCustom:


<WindowManager>:
    MainWindow:
    NewContact:
    ModContact:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have named your `kv` file as `main.kv` it will be loaded automatically as described in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv). However, you are also loading that same file with the line:

```
kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
```

Loading the same `kv` file more than once can lead to unexpected results and you are seeing one such result. You can avoid the error you are seeing by simply eliminating the above line, or by changing the name of your `kv` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for solving that problem but now i get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'lista'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/...PycharmProjects/RUBRICA/main.py", line 62, in <module>
     application.run()
   File "C:\...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:/...PycharmProjects/RUBRICA/main.py", line 57, in build
     self.screens[0].ids.lista.data = [{'text='+ str(x)} for x in range(30)]
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

I think, like it's said, it's a problem related to the data loading (`self.screens[0].ids.lista_di_dati.data = [{'text='+ str(x)} for x in range(30)]`)

Comment: You need to submit a separate question.